# Unable to fetch Resultset from StoredProc in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

We are trying to execute stored proc in Java which looks like as below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc] 
(
    @input1 varchar(20),
    @input2 varchar(20),
    @responsecode       varchar(10) output
)
AS

//Implementation

SELECT @a,@b,@c,@d;

SELECT @responsecode;
```

Java Code looks like as below,

```
callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{call MyProc("2","2"))}");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);           
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4,Types.JAVA_OBJECT);
```

As you can see , we are trying to get two output parameters from stored proc,

We are able to get response code  at index 3 , however @a,@b,@c,@d  should come as resulset at index 4 ( may be I am wrong)

Can you please give me some poninters on getting resultset for such kind of stored proc.

when I execute this stored proc in Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio, I can see two types of responses, first is resultset and other one is  ResponseCode as below,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up resultsets with output parameters. The stored procedure in your post only has one output parameter, `@responsecode`.

Output parameters do not need to be selected out after you set them in a proc:

```
create procedure testsp (@param int output)
as
    set @param = 1

GO

declare @param int

exec testsp @param output


select @param
```

So remove the `SELECT @responsecode;`, and also the 4th registered parameter in your callable statement.

To get to your data, iterate over the resultset returned by `executeQuery()`.

Comment: By Executing executeQuery(), we are getting resultset, but then How I will get response code

Comment: Using `callableStatement.getString(3)`